# In the phrase "a button click", what are the parts of speech of each word?

Tags: grammar

In technical writing, if we say something like "the user performed **a button click**, which took them to the next page," what part of speech is "click"? Is it a noun, since the click is an event, and the button is the thing which received the event? Or is it a verb, since a click is an action? Also, I am confused about what part of speech "button" is since it is "qualifying" the click, in a way.

Answer (score 4):

"Button click" is a compound noun. Each can also be nouns on their own. Click can be a verb, such as in "Next you will click the button." I suppose one could debate whether the compound noun "button click" is made up of a noun and noun or a noun and verb, but I would say it is a noun and noun but that the distinction is irrelevant. When I perform a click [noun] on "Post", this answer will appear. As when I click [verb] on "Post".

> Compound Nouns
>   A compound noun is a noun that is made with two or more words. A compound noun is usually [noun + noun] or [adjective + noun], but there are other combinations (see below). It is important to understand and recognize compound nouns. Each compound noun acts as a single unit and can be modified by adjectives and other nouns.

From: https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-compound.htm

EDIT: Reread your specific question. If button were not there, click would definitely be a noun. It is the object of perform.

Comment: It is possible you are right, but I think it is a mere modifer+head pair rather than a compound noun. I gave reasons at the end of my own answer. Briefly, in compound nouns we cannot separately modify the constituent nouns, whereas we can do so in a modifier+head pair. So *London colleges* is not a compund noun because we can do things like this: *London theological colleges*. On the other hand, *ice cream* is a compound noun, because we can't say things like *ice and custard creams*. Now consider *a left-button click.* This tends to show that *button click* is a mere modifier+head pair.

Comment: For me, "click of a button" which becomes ""a button click" has become a compound noun. In the blink of an eye has probably already been expressed as: in an eye blink.

Answer (score 3):

The word group

*a button click*

is a **noun phrase** (NP) whose [head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(linguistics)) is the noun *click*. One way to see that *click* is a noun is to realize that it can be pluralized: *two button **clicks***. Incidentally, this also shows that it is *click* that is the head of the NP (rather than *button,* which remains in the singular).

The word *button* is also a noun. It is clearly not a verb, or a preposition, of a determinative, or an adverb. The only thing it could plausibly be, apart from a noun, is an adjective. But it is not an adjective either, because it can be modified by an adjective: *a large-button click.* If it were an adjective, its modifier would have to be an adverb, so *largely*.

Finally, *a* is an article, which older sources classify as an adjective, while contemporary grammars would say it is a separate part of speech, a *determinative.* Its grammatical role in the NP is that of a *determiner.*

We say that *button* plays the role of a **pre-head internal dependent in NP structure.**

In general, internal dependents can be either modifiers or complements. The most important characteristic that distinguishes the two is that a complement must be **licensed** by the head noun (shortly it will become clear what this means). [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468) says (p. 439-443) that with pre-head complements, we

> typically have close paraphrases involving post-head complements where a forced choice of preposition is observable. Compare, for example, *an **alcohol** ban* and *a ban **on alcohol,*** *a **wrist** injury* and *an injury **to the wrist.*** Similarly, corresponding to *a **legal** adviser* ([iii]) we have *an adviser **on legal matters.***

It is the fact that we don't have a choice which proposition to use that makes it licensed (in the sense that other prepositions then *aren't* licensed).

In our case we would have *a click **of** a button,* where *of* cannot be replaced by any other preposition. Thus, it is licensed; thus, *button* is a complement of *click*.

**Compound noun vs. modifier+head pair**

A priori, there is a possibility that *button click* is a compound noun. The way to distinguish compound nouns from mere modifer+head pairs ('composite nominals', as CGEL calls them) is that in the latter case, the two nouns can enter separately into relations of coordination and modification ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468), p. 448-451). As an example, consider *London colleges.* Is it a compund noun, or a modifier+head pair? The acceptability of the following shows that it is the latter: *various [London and Oxford] colleges*; *various London [schools and colleges]*. In contrast, *ice cream* is a compound noun, because we can't have <sup>*</sup>*[ice and custard] creams*; we have to say *ice creams and custard creams*. Similarly, we can't say <sup>*</sup>*crushed ice cream* when we mean *cream of crushed ice*. In contrast, we may say *London theological colleges*, where *colleges* is separately modified by *theological*. There are other criteria that can be considered as well.

As for *a button click,* I believe the following shows that it is not a composite noun:

*a **left-** button click* [(examples)](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1600&bih=778&tbs=bkv%3Ap&tbm=bks&ei=i6hAXczeC--c5wKBxrvgBg&q=%22a+left-button+click%22&oq=%22a+left-button+click%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...31830.32969.0.33445.5.5.0.0.0.0.110.466.3j2.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.195...33i10k1.0.ko8JeVpmKDU)

An additional consideration is this: compound nouns (like *bus stop*) tend to have separate entries in dictionaries [(like this)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bus%20stop), whereas *button click* doesn't have one in any of the dictionaries I looked at, including the *OED.* Here they are: [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/button%20click), [*Lexico*](https://www.lexico.com/en/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=dictionary&dictionary=en&query=button+click) (formerly *Oxford*), [*American Heritage*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=button+click), [*Collins*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/), [*vocabulary.com*](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/button%20click), [*Macmillan*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/spellcheck/british/?q=button+click), [*Cambridge*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=button+click), [*Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=button+click&title=Special%3ASearch&go=Go&ns0=1), [*Webster's New World College Dictionary, Fifth Ed.*](https://www.yourdictionary.com/search/) (via yourdictionary.com), [*Infoplease*](https://www.infoplease.com/spellcheck/button%20click), [*dictionary.com*](https://www.dictionary.com/misspelling?term=button%20click&s=t), and [*freedictionary.org*](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=button+click).

Comment: There are many examples in English of words that become, or function like, a compound noun in usage and that are not in a dictionary. Something can be a noun phrase and a noun, simultaneously.

Comment: @Lambie Right; that's why I said *tend* to have. It's not a decisive criterion.